# Attempted import error: 'Navlink' is not exported from 'react-router-dom'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, yarnpkg

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navbar, NavbarBrand, Nav, NavbarToggler, Collapse, NavItem, Jumbotron } from 'reactstrap';
import { Navlink } from 'react-router-dom';
```

I have installed the router by using the command in the terminal `yarn add react-router-dom@4.2.2`. But it shows the above error.

I Used Navlink code in the HeaderComponent.js file given below

```
<NavItem>
  <Navlink className="nav-link" to="/home">
    <span className="fa fa-home fa-sm"> Home</span>
  </Navlink>
</NavItem>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: You have a typo, change `Navlink` to `NavLink`.

Answer (score 1):

Just change `Navlink` to `NavLink`

Answer (score 0):

Your import should have `NavLink` instead of `Navlink`. Make changes like done below:

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom';

<NavItem>
  <NavLink className="nav-link" to="/home">
    <span className="fa fa-home fa-sm"> Home</span>
  </NavLink>
</NavItem>
```